# Getting a SQLiteException and I'm not sure what's causing it

Tags: android, sqlite

My Android app is crashing with this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  315): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x3470a0
...
E/AndroidRuntime(  315):        at lee.medical.icu.dataentry.db.PatientInfoDbHelper.getTests(PatientInfoDbHelper.java:163)
```

It's stumbling on this bit of code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = {C_LOCATION, C_TESTS};
String selection = "? = '?' and ? = '?'";
String[] selectionArgs = {C_LAST, lastName, C_FIRST, firstName};
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs,
        null, null, null); // line 163
```

What could this error mean?

(A couple of notes: `C_LOCATION`, `C_TESTS`, `C_LAST`, and `C_FIRST` are columns in my database. `lastName` and `firstName` are method arguments that are self-explanatory.)

**Edit**: I had to play around with antlersoft's solution a bit to make it work. In case anyone else having the same problem stumbles upon this question, the solution in my case was to change the `selection` to:

```
String selection = C_LAST + " = ? and " + C_FIRST + " = ?"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your ? in single-quotes for string arguments; in single quotes the ? is taken as a literal string and not as an argument placeholder--  SQLite will know the type of the argument passed as ? and so you don't have to quote it.

The way you have written it there are four arguments and only two argument placeholders in your query and so the exception.